# SIGSEGV Error at the right end of program Code::Blocks

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks, segmentation-fault

my program is a "calculator" (+, -, *, /, %) on big numbers and I'm using arrays to do it.
It's doing all fine except for precise numbers on division.
Example: With "235904955217602177779531391566404600024660137230836722833991048650026087431751987982144871621272505722819200445400 / 291608731024614095661614", it returns the good answer but crash right after. I've been debugging and recieved a SIGSEGV error. But it's happening right at the end of the program. I have no clue where does this error come from.

[Here is the debug error.](https://pastebin.com/AAwjjfR2)

```
[debug]Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

[Here is the full program.](https://pastebin.com/Vebye0sC)

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segmentation fault i.e. SIGSEGV on program exit typically happens when you corrupt memory, e.g. in case of buffer overflow. In another words it's not always correspond to the moment of corruption but can appear far later after it. So, first try to enable and fix all compile warnings, add input arguments checking, asserts before accessing buffers if index is within boundaries, then it's good practice to use some static code analyzer, e.g. lint. This is to ensure code quality.

Another option if you catch it always with some specific inputs - is trying to isolate the piece of code that is to blame: by varying inputs and/or by short-cutting functions in code you could eventually find it. But this is not systemic approach, there could be other fault scenarios.